# Load images one after another in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

My problem is, I have multiple images and want to load like pre-loader, but the problem is that I want to start load of the second image after completing the first one. In my current code I store all images in one array and using a loop load all images (give the source of all images of the array to an image object), and then all images start loading.

Comment: I have array like arr['1.jpg', '2.jpg','3.jpg'] contains images and load 1.jpg first then after completing 1. jpg load 2.jpg and so all... , image those complete loading will be stored in another array

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want to have a look at the load event.

```
function loadImagesInSequence(images) {
  if (!images.length) {
    return;
  }

  var img = new Image(),
      url = images.shift();

  img.onload = function(){ loadImagesInSequence(images) };
  img.src = url;
}

loadImagesInSequence(['a.png', 'b.png', 'c.png']);
```

whenever an image is loaded, the load event is fired. When that happens, we execute the loadImagesInSequence() again. We won't load the same image twice, as `Array.shift()` removed from the array we simply passed through.

Comment: +1 You should call `shift()` before setting `img.onload` - I know that it works but it's confusing: If you don't know JavaScript well, you could assume that a "copy" of the images array is made for the call and the `shift()` has no effect (or the effect happens after preparing the function call).