# Best solution for Slider to load images one by one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loading

I have a Slider with 7 big images and i'm looking for a javascript/ajax solution to load this images one by one. The browser should begin to download the second image only when the first is complete, etc..

What's the best practice for that need ?

For now, I got 2 approaches :

- [Load images one after another in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412137/load-images-one-after-another-in-javascript)
- http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Thanks !

Comment: The best solution would be to find a slider that lazyloads the images internally, or build your own slider that does the same, it's not that hard!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Image constructor and defining its `src` property, the image will begin downloading. Register an onload event for the image and ensure that it's downloaded before inserting the image into the DOM.

[A simple preloading example](http://jsfiddle.net/W4PJN/)